# ¿Cómo especificar en esta consulta que los registros sean de la última hora?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Tengo la siguiente consulta, que verifica que los resultados sean del día actual (de hoy), pero requiero que se consulten solo los últimos registros de hoy, de la última hora, y no no sé como restarle a `now()` una hora.

```
$properties = Property::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->whereDate('created_at', NOW())->get();
```

Comment: ¿Qué es para ti última hora? Proporciona un ejemplo.

Comment: Sí actualmente son las 6:50, obtener si existen los registros desde las 5:50 hasta las 6.50 del día de hoy

Comment: Prueba con el método [`whereBetween()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#where-clauses).

Comment: Gracias, sí lo haré... @HeytalePazguato me dió unas sugerencias, entre ellas `whereBetween()` ya lo hago.

Comment: @Sal, gracias, ese fue el que funcionó!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Puedes intentar con cualquiera de los siguientes métodos

Método 1, utilizando `subHour`:

```
$properties = Property::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subHour())->get();
```

Método 2, utilizando `subMinutes`:

```
$properties = Property::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subMinutes(60))->get();
```

Método 3, utilizando `subMinutes` (También podría ser `subHour`) con `whereBetween`:

```
$properties = Property::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->whereBetween('created_at', [now()->subMinutes(60), now()])->get();
```